# Debian 6.0.3, Freeradius 2.1.10, PostgreSQL 8.4 High memory Usage

Tags: debian, postgresql, freeradius

We are running a Freeradius server on a VMware server and we have a high memory usage that I am trying to troubleshoot.
We are running the PostgreSQL 8.4 as the database backend on the same server for the radius server. This issue has been
discovered because we are monitoring the server with OpenNMS. We see that it is reaching his memory limit and start swapping
on time to time.

This is the memory usage:

```
free -m
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:          2013       1972         41          0        322        284
  -/+ buffers/cache:       1364        648
  Swap:          382          0        382
```

if I do top -d1 and I press m to sort them by memory usage:

```
 top - 10:37:40 up 6 days,  2:20,  2 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.02, 0.00
  Tasks: 102 total,   1 running, 101 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
  Cpu(s):  2.0%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.1%id,  1.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
   7914 postgres  20   0  102m  22m  21m S  1.0  1.1   0:06.44 postgres
   8833 root      20   0 19064 1336 1000 R  1.0  0.1   0:00.03 top
      1 root      20   0  8352  808  676 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.07 init
      2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
      3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
      4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.39 ksoftirqd/0
      5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
      6 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.40 events/0
      7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset
      8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
      9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
     10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 async/mgr
     11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 pm
     12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.25 sync_supers
     13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.43 bdi-default
     14 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/0
     15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.70 kblockd/0
```

HTOP revealed morre info about the processes childrens:
[htop picture](http://i40.tinypic.com/rbziwj.png)

If I look at the processes with children, I can see that postgresql seems to be eating all the ram:

```
~:ps auxf
  USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
  root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00 [kthreadd]
  root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [migration/0]
  root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
  root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [watchdog/0]
  root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:03  \_ [events/0]
  root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [cpuset]
  root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [khelper]
  root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [netns]
  root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [async/mgr]
  root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [pm]
  root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [sync_supers]
  root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [bdi-default]
  root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kintegrityd/0]
  root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kblockd/0]
  root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kacpid]
  root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kacpi_notify]
  root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kacpi_hotplug]
  root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kseriod]
  root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kondemand/0]
  root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [khungtaskd]
  root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kswapd0]
  root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Nov03   0:00  \_ [ksmd]
  root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [aio/0]
  root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [crypto/0]
  root       210  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [ata/0]
  root       211  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [ata_aux]
  root       212  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_0]
  root       213  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_1]
  root       219  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:02  \_ [mpt_poll_0]
  root       220  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [mpt/0]
  root       225  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_2]
  root       258  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:14  \_ [kjournald]
  root       557  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:00  \_ [kpsmoused]
  root       637  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:03  \_ [flush-8:0]
  root      1164  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov03   0:03  \_ [vmmemctl]
  root         1  0.0  0.0   8352   808 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:04 init [2]
  root       331  0.0  0.0  16848   984 ?        S<s  Nov03   0:00 udevd --daemon
  root       783  0.0  0.0  16876   880 ?        S<   Nov03   0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
  root       784  0.0  0.0  16876   816 ?        S<   Nov03   0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
  daemon     861  0.0  0.0   8092   536 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:00 /sbin/portmap
  statd      873  0.0  0.0  14376   868 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:00 /sbin/rpc.statd
  root      1034  0.0  0.0  54552  2032 ?        Sl   Nov03   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c4
  root      1087  0.0  0.0   3916   628 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
  root      1262  0.0  0.1  66612  3164 ?        Sl   Nov03   2:51 /usr/sbin/vmtoolsd
  root      1289  0.0  0.5 151660 11176 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  www-data  9998  0.0  0.2 151660  5832 ?        S    Nov06   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  www-data  9999  0.0  0.3 151804  6408 ?        S    Nov06   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  www-data 10000  0.0  0.2 151660  5832 ?        S    Nov06   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  www-data 10001  0.0  0.2 151660  5832 ?        S    Nov06   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  www-data 10002  0.0  0.2 151660  5832 ?        S    Nov06   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  daemon    1301  0.0  0.0  18708   436 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
  root      1332  0.0  0.0  22420  1056 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
  root      1408  0.0  0.0  49168  1144 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
  root     20007  0.0  0.1  70452  3384 ?        Ss   08:56   0:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/0
  root     20042  0.0  0.3  24160  7044 pts/0    Ss   08:56   0:00      \_ -bash
  root     14246  0.0  0.0  16444  1140 pts/0    R+   10:41   0:00          \_ ps auxf
  snmp      1416  0.0  0.2  47636  5220 ?        S    Nov03   0:48 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid
  root      1417  0.4  0.0  43788  2004 ?        Ss   Nov03  36:22 /usr/sbin/snmptrapd -Ln -n -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid
  root      1427  0.0  0.1  53084  2432 ?        Ss   Nov03   3:12 /usr/sbin/dvtrap -D
  101       1755  0.0  0.0  44140  1060 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m
  freerad   1803  0.0  1.1 330624 24280 ?        Ssl  Nov03   6:33 /usr/sbin/freeradius
  root      1825  0.0  0.0  51856  1424 tty1     Ss   Nov03   0:00 /bin/login --
  root      1980  0.0  0.3  24096  6940 tty1     S+   Nov03   0:00  \_ -bash
  root      1826  0.0  0.0   5928   620 tty2     Ss+  Nov03   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
  root      1827  0.0  0.0   5928   620 tty3     Ss+  Nov03   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty3
  root      1828  0.0  0.0   5928   620 tty4     Ss+  Nov03   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty4
  root      1829  0.0  0.0   5928   620 tty5     Ss+  Nov03   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty5
  root      1830  0.0  0.0   5928   620 tty6     Ss+  Nov03   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty6
  postgres  7890  0.0  0.3 104964  6788 ?        S    Nov08   0:01 /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main -c config_file=/etc
  postgres  7914  0.0  1.1 105064 22796 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:06  \_ postgres: writer process
  postgres  7915  0.0  0.0 104964  1644 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: wal writer process
  postgres  7916  0.0  0.0 105240  1848 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: autovacuum launcher process
  postgres  7917  0.0  0.0  72320  1532 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:02  \_ postgres: stats collector process
  postgres  7924  0.0  1.2 107468 25000 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(51997) idle
  postgres  7927  0.0  1.2 107520 24876 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(51998) idle
  postgres  7939  0.0  1.2 107512 24820 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(51999) idle
  postgres  7941  0.0  1.2 107512 24896 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52000) idle
  postgres  7951  0.0  1.2 107468 24876 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52001) idle
  postgres  7959  0.0  1.2 107468 25112 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52002) idle
  postgres  7962  0.0  1.2 107472 24908 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52003) idle
  postgres  7963  0.0  1.2 107472 24968 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52004) idle
  postgres  7966  0.0  1.2 107472 24852 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52005) idle
  postgres  7969  0.0  1.2 107468 24956 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52006) idle
  postgres  7986  0.0  1.2 107468 24988 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52007) idle
  postgres  7989  0.0  1.2 107468 25000 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52008) idle
  postgres  8017  0.0  1.2 107472 24792 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52009) idle
  postgres  8022  0.0  1.2 107516 24788 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52010) idle
  postgres  8025  0.0  1.2 107472 24868 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52011) idle
  postgres  8028  0.0  1.2 107468 24776 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52012) idle
  postgres  8034  0.0  1.2 107472 24880 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52013) idle
  postgres  8035  0.0  1.2 107472 24932 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52014) idle
  postgres  8054  0.0  1.2 107516 24960 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52015) idle
  postgres  9559  0.0  1.2 107468 24756 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52020) idle
  postgres  9566  0.0  1.2 107472 24788 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52021) idle
  postgres  9569  0.0  1.2 107472 24832 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52022) idle
  postgres  9572  0.0  1.2 107468 24832 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52023) idle
  postgres  9573  0.0  1.2 107472 24804 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52024) idle
  postgres  9574  0.0  1.2 107472 24948 ?        Ss   Nov08   0:01  \_ postgres: radadm radius 127.0.0.1(52025) idle
  postgres 31797  0.0  0.4 106292  9576 ?        Ss   10:31   0:00  \_ postgres: radadm radius 172.30.64.102(3128) idle
  postgres  3146  0.0  0.4 106292  8708 ?        Ss   10:33   0:00  \_ postgres: radadm radius 172.30.64.101(3595) idle
  postgres  8607  0.0  0.3 106292  7032 ?        Ss   10:37   0:00  \_ postgres: radadm radius 172.30.64.103(2579) idle
```

What can I change to make postgresql eat less ram or to free some ram?

thank you.